# To create a CrystalReport from a "Specific date to other"

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have few data in the database for which a crystal report has to generated.  I need to generate a crystal report from a particular date to other date.For example Report between 14.5.2014 to 16.5.14 has to be generated.How to generate it?Any sample code would be of great help.Note:Its Windows application using c#.net

```
enter code here
```

StrSQL = " SELECT vcCatId, vcCatSubId,vcitemid,vcitemname FROM item WHERE `vcItemId`";
                StrSQL += " IN (SELECT vcItemId FROM `order_items` WHERE `vcInTime`";
                StrSQL += " BETWEEN '" + StartDate + "'  AND '" + EndDate + "')";

Have used the following query to fetch the report.Its working properly when I use it for a single table.When multiple tables are selected its not considering date as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just stick to simple way

Imagine your report viewer object is ReportViewer

```
ReportViewer.SelectionFormula = " Date({Table1.Date1})>= #" + Date1.Text+ "# And     Date({Table1.Date2})<= #" + Date2.Text + "#";

ReportViewer. RefreshReport();
```

Let me know if it’s not working or if you need more details

Comment: The problem is it works for a single table but,when I am using multiple tables It is not taking date as a parameter.

Comment: Hi there sorry for the late reply could you post your table link screenshot over here which showing in crustal report.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="ExpiryReportCrystalReportViewer" runat="server" 
                AutoDataBind="true"
                EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" EnableDrillDown="False" 
                EnableParameterPrompt="False" HasCrystalLogo="False" HasDrilldownTabs="False" 
                HasDrillUpButton="False" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" 
                HasToggleParameterPanelButton="False" ToolPanelView="None" ToolPanelWidth="" 
                Width="350px"/>

ReportDocument RptDoc = new ReportDocument();
  ExpiryReportCrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = RptDoc;
                    Session["EDR"] = dsDocument;
```

Its difficult to answer your question since it is not specific.Please be more specific next time.This is sample for crystal report.
Hope it helps in some way.

Comment: Please note its not web application.Its windowsapp